# What is the proper way to ask CW questions now?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki, etiquette

If you ask a question that you know should be CW, should you flag for a moderator immediately after asking?

Remind me again why you removed the option for authors to mark new questions as CW.

Comment: I think that the proper way to ask a question that would formally have been CW is not to ask it. I could well be wrong on that point though.

Answer (score 11):

> If you ask a question that you know should be CW (...)

Chances are the question is not appropriate, consider not asking it, or rephrasing it until you no longer *know* it should be CW

> Remind me again why you removed the Author's option to mark it as CW?

Because it was confusing, and also people used it as an excuse to ask questions not quite appropriate

That said, If you really need to ask it, flag it for mod attention and ask for it to be converted.

Comment: To add onto this answer, also check out [Sam Saffron's answer here, and the discussion of that question in general](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67039/what-can-we-do-to-make-community-wiki-better/67192#67192).

Comment: Well, I will continue asking such questions, because I think they add value to me and to the community. And I will flag them.

Comment: @rip, if the community agrees, you won't have any problems.

Comment: @rip: *Or*, you could ask them at [the place specifically setup to accommodate those questions](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), where you can *know* that you won't have any problems. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Downvoter, to be fair, it's more like "if a mod agrees," than "if the community agrees." (And I'm okay with that.)

Comment: @dmckee, FWIW, [Robert disagrees](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67784/so-shouldnt-allow-subjective-questions-in-october-2010/67804#67804) with using Programmers SE as "the subjective SO."

Comment: @Pop I think everyone disagrees with him though, including most of the population of the Programmers SE

Comment: @Pop "Community agrees" is more about the community deciding the allowance and value of the questions moreso than the task of CW conversion. I find it more useful to wait for the discussion first than to just slap on CW at request, if I think it's a particularly borderline or non-appropriate case.

Comment: @Pop: My observation about those questions that survived on SO as CW was that they were good questions (i.e. not a simple as *"which do you like..."* ), but not answerable in terms of code or history. I.e. they were exactly what Robert is asking for.

Comment: @Michael, I disagree with Robert too; heck, I asked that question that Robert was answering. But he is still __Robert__. Also, that answer has more upvotes than my question.

Comment: @dmckee, that's fine, but irrelevant to the point I was trying to make. I'm just saying that The Powers don't seem to want people to think "Programmers SE = subjective SO" as a blanket statement.

Comment: @dmckee, @Pop - I was not referring to Stack Overflow specifically but rather to the entire network. While SO has Programmers, most/all other SE sites don't have such a parallel.